# Loop issues when counting lines in a .csv

Tags: c++, csv

It's me again still working on learning how it is possible for me to manage and manipulate .csv files using c++. I've made a small program that creates a new .csv file, fills in the table headings with generic labels, all named "value" for demonstrative purposes.
I then close the file to be sure any changes I made are saved. I then re-open that same file and count the number of lines in the file. I again close the file, and now open a file with references to the values that need to be filled in to the newly created file. I then count the lines of this file and compare them to the number of lines of the newly created file. If the new file has fewer lines than the reference file I need to identify the last line of the new file, add one to that number, and then read the values from that number line in the refrence file to then add the values to that new file.

Now comes to my problems. The program will accurately tell how many lines each file has. Great so far, but when i try to say check if the new file has fewer lines on it in a while loop it is doing something to just keep adding to the numbers of line and in an if staement it only checks once. This is probably a really stupid error like, I should have the whole program in a while loop or something but I do not want the first step of inserting the table headings to be repeated. Any help is appreciated.

I may not be wording myself correctly, If anyone is confused by what I;m saying but think that they can help me solve this issue just ask me to clarify.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char c;
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    int loop=1;
    ofstream mynewfile;
    mynewfile.open("MyNewFile.csv");

    if (mynewfile.good())
    {
        mynewfile << "Value,Value,Value,Value,Value,Value," <<endl;
        //End of if mynewfile.good()
    }

    mynewfile.close();

    while(loop==1)
    {
        ifstream mynewfile2;
        mynewfile2.open ("MyNewFile.csv");
        while (mynewfile2.good())
        {
            c = mynewfile2.get();
            if (c=='\n')
                x++;
            //End of while(mynewfile2.good())
        }

        mynewfile2.close();
        ifstream myoldfile;
        myoldfile.open ("MyOldFile.csv");

        while (myoldfile.good())
        {
          c = myoldfile.get();
          if (c=='\n')
              y++;
        }

        myoldfile.close();

        cout << "The Number of lines in the file are " << x << endl;
        cout << "The Number of lines in the file are " << y << endl;

        if(x < y)
        {
          cout << "Keep Going" << endl;
        }
        else if(x = y)
        {
          system("PAUSE");
        }
        else
        {
            loop == 0;
        }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;

    //End of main()
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what this sentence says:  "Great so far, but when i try to say check if the new file has fewer lines on it in a while loop it is doing something to just keep adding to the numbers of line and in an if staement it only checks once."

Comment: I don't see `loop` ever getting used. What's that there for? What's `system("PAUSE")` there for? `using namespace std;` -- blech!

Comment: When I change the 'if(loop==1)' to 'while(loop==1)' for some reason the program just keeps adding large intervals where the if loop returns the correct numbers but wont repeat.

Comment: When can loop ever be set to one?

Comment: or zero, if that is the break condition?

Comment: The loop is always set to one until the new file equals the size of the refrence. The refrence is 14 lines long. The new file is one. I want to say go to line 2 of the refrence file. Grab the values i need, put them in line two of the new file count the lines again and keep going until both files have the 14 lines of values in them. I need to do this though one line at a time.

Comment: Billy you bastard, I haven't seen you in years. Is there some way you could get in touch with me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You made a classic C/C++ error.  This line:

```
else if(x = y)
```

assigns the value of y to x.  It evaluates to true if y is non-zero.  What you meant was this:

```
else if(x == y)
```

Comment: yes but if you change the if to while the loop still does not stop because they are never equal. It for some reson counts the second time  as a higher number.

Comment: The loop never ends because you will never set loop to zero (unless MyOldFile.csv has no newlines).  Fix the error I pointed out above.

Comment: I did but when you change the if to while it is reading lines that are not there.

Comment: In fact, I'm curious. What warning level do you use when you compile?  -W3 or above would have told you what's wrong with your code:

foo.cpp(63): warning C4553: '==' : operator has no effect; did you intend '='?